# Jupyter Notebook Installation

Tags: apt, software-installation, python, python-2.7, ipython

Is it possible to install Jupyter Notebook through `apt-get install`? For example, we can install numpy by using `apt-get install python-numpy`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

#### Ubuntu 22.04 and later

```
sudo apt install epiphany jupyter-notebook
```

Create `jupyter_notebook_config.py` by:

```
jupyter notebook --generate-config # type y for yes at the prompt
```

Then open `~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` for editing in a text editor and change:

```
# c.NotebookApp.browser = ''
```

to:

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = '/usr/bin/epiphany'
```

Don't forget to delete the `#` at the beginning of the line so it's not a comment anymore. You can use a different web browser if you don't like Web as long as it's not a snap package and you change the path from `/usr/bin/epiphany` to the path to your web browser which you can find by running a command of the form `which my-web-browser`.

It still won't work though, so you have to do one more step. Change the ownership of the `~/.local/share/jupyter` directory from **root** to **user**. Instead of **user** in the below command replace it with your own username that you login with.

```
sudo chown -R user:user ~/.local/share/jupyter
```

#### Ubuntu 20.04

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install jupyter-notebook jupyter # jupyter is optional
```

#### Ubuntu 18.04-19.10

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install python3-notebook jupyter jupyter-core python-ipykernel
```

To start the notebook server run the following command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

You should see Jupyter Notebook open in your web browser.

---

**Ubuntu 17.04 and 17.10**

In Ubuntu 17.04 and later Jupyter Notebook is available in the default Ubuntu repositories and can be quickly and easily installed using apt. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install jupyter-notebook jupyter-core python-ipykernel
```

python-ipykernel is necessary for running Python 2.x programs in Jupyter Notebook, which otherwise supports only Python 3.x.

To start the notebook server run the following command:

```
jupyter notebook
```

You should see Jupyter Notebook open in your web browser

**Ubuntu 16.04 and earlier**

Google Colaboratory is Google's free Jupyter notebook environment that requires no setup and runs entirely in the cloud.

Comment: I get following error: `$jupyter notebook`
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: The command `jupyter-troubleshoot` will help you to troubleshoot this problem.

Comment: I removed a lot of python packages and reinstalled them. Now it works, but I dont know why. But thats fine for me. Thank you.

Comment: You also need `apt-get install jupyter-notebook`, as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42648610/error-when-executing-jupyter-notebook-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04 users can use the 18.04 command above, but should not include python-ipykernel.

Comment: Looks like in 20.04 `apt-get install jupyter-notebook` is enough.

Answer (score 12):

I installed it using

```
pip install jupyter
```

(*pip3* if Python3 is installed; also, ensure you have root access, i.e. logged in to the terminal as *root@...*)

and for python dependencies

```
apt-get install build-essential python3-dev
```

In ubuntu desktop 14.04.3 LTS. I am on python3.

Comment: Jupyter not include in Ubuntu repositories?

Comment: @EdwardSiew. I don't think so. I was following one of the training sessions...they also mentioned to install it this way only.

Comment: What if we don't have the root access?

Comment: @AVINASHANAND probably useless a year later, but perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7143077/how-can-i-install-packages-in-my-home-folder-with-pip): `pip install --user pkg_name`.

Comment: @AVINASHANAND you should be able to do sudo to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be possible using only apt-get.

```
apt-file find jupyter ## returns no results
```

For 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install --upgrade pip ## secret sauce -- pip fails otherwise
sudo pip install jupyter
```

then

```
jupyter notebook
```

---

Replace 'pip' with 'pip3' for use with Python3.

Answer (score 0):

Install it using

```
sudo -H pip install jupyter
```

After installation completes, use the following command

```
jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on official recommendation [here](http://jupyter.org/install) we should use:

```
python -m pip install jupyter
python3 -m pip install jupyter
```

After this command and all of the previous I had a problem with permission error. To resolve it we should use next command:

```
python -m pip install jupyter --user
python3 -m pip install jupyter --user
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo -H pip3 install jupyter` (with `pip3`, not `pip`) worked for me after numerous other approaches.  I did this on the ubuntu linux with python 3.5.3  built into lavano chromebook c330. Also installed spyder and numerous favorite commands like "locate".

Comment: This answer is a duplicate of this existing answer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/737094/jupyter-notebook-installation/1005871#1005871