# problem installing jupyter on ubuntu

Tags: python-2.7

ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyzmq-18.0.2.dist-info'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  Could you provide the exact command that lead to this error?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What command is this output related to? Please [edit] your question to include it. Most importantly: Have you run the command using `sudo` / as root?

Comment: why isn't the webapp enough? https://gke.mybinder.org/v2/gh/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-demo/master?urlpath=lab%2Ftree%2Fdemo%2FLorenz.ipynb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jupyter Notebook Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737094/jupyter-notebook-installation)

Answer (score 0):

the webapps work just fine : https://jupyter.org/try

but if you inisist on having it offline here's a guide

download this : https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh

in a terminal :

```
cd Downloads
sudo apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa libxrandr2 libxrandr2 libxss1 libxcursor1 libxcomposite1 libasound2 libxi6 libxtst6
sudo ./Anaconda3-2019.03-Linux-x86_64.sh 
jupyter notebook
```