# Jupyter Notebook not opening in firefox

Tags: jupyter

I am getting this error "The file at /home/ankit/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-8468-open.html is not readable." while trying to open jupyter notebook in ubuntu22.04 terminal. I tried Edit the configuration file ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py and set: c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file = False, But it didnt work in my case. Btw i am using the Notebook by Ctrl+clicking on the link in terminal

Comment: Workaround: Don't change the jupyter configuration file, and rather replace the snap version of Firefox with apt. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 (jammy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22)

Comment: Is this  the only option?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jupyter Notebook Installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/737094/jupyter-notebook-installation)

Answer (score 0):

Snap installations of Firefox can't open files under paths starting with a `.`, and By default, Firefox created a shortcut under `.local`, for example, in my system:

```
file:///home/fccoelho/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-123966-open.html
```

so all you need to do is to set these environmental variables in your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
JUPYTER_DATA_DIR=/home/$USER/Public
JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR=/home/$USER/Public
```

or  if you use fish shell, like me:

```
set -Ux JUPYTER_DATA_DIR /home/$USER/Public
set -Ux JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR /home/$USER/Public
```

directly in the terminal, and they will persist even after reboot.